# Not able to see the table created in intellij idea

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea, jdbc

Error loading data for table "mysql57.addressbook".

Database error message: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

[image: error]

Comment: Would be nice to see your SQL code as well

Comment: @esin88 I have created a table in mysql workbench and when I want to see the table in intellij idea, the above error pops up.. You are asking for which code?

Comment: ah, in that case (it looked like you created a table in IntelliJ IDEA), it might be IDEA bug. Would make sense to report it

Comment: @esin88 I created a table in mysql workbench...and using dB browser in intellij idea I used it.... For other tables there is no error but for this table the above error is shown

Comment: If you are using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate, try using [bundled Database integration support](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/features/). If it is not an option and you are continue having the issue, please report to the [Database Navigator plugin vendor](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1800-database-navigator)

Comment: But I am getting the above error for only one table not for the other tables I made

Comment: 1. Can you load the table using other tools?  2. Can you post the DML of the table?

Comment: yes i am able to load the table by executing the sql commands in database console.